# Preview VBA code files in Windows 7 Explorer

Tags: windows, vba, registry, preview, explorer

I just found out that Windows Explorer has a preview pane which can view different types of files. For example, my version came with ".txt" and ".xlsx" files enabled for previewing. This is really useful for looking at a directory full of text or spreadsheet files.

I followed a procedure I found on the web to enable previewing other types of files as well, including ".log" and ".list", and code files like ".bas", ".cls", and ".frm" (VBA). To do this, I just added the string item "PerceivedType" as "text" to the registry key for each type under Classes Root.

Unfortunately, even though I configured ".bas" in exactly the same fashion as the others, Explorer insists there's "No preview available". I carefully checked the registry settings and I'm certain there's no difference in the ones I've found that seem to be relevant. I also tried this on a Windows 10 machine with the same results.

So I must be missing something.

Any suggestions on where to look to fix this?

Comment: The down-vote contributes nothing to the discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext]
@="extfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\extfile]
@="ext file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\extfile\shellex\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: This works if I rename files to .vba, but I'd prefer to stick with the original, supported file extension and make it work correctly.

Comment: You can use any extension. Just replace ext in the sample.

Comment: I searched for further information on the GUIDs used and now have a much better understanding of how this all works.